# Ubuntu server startup getty autologin interrupt to login to custom user

Tags: server, 18.04, login, auto-login

Right now I have autologin enabled for my ubuntu server

```
sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1
```

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a user1 --noclear %I $TERM
Type=idle
```

But I want to have a delay before autologin and allow users to interrupt the autologin and instead login as some other user by manually entering username and password.

In short:

- Boot up If idle for x second,
- autologin to user1 Otherwise,
- user should be login to some other account

Anyone can point to right direction on how can this be achieved.

Comment: Give you some hints. 1) add a delay to your service, such let it be triggered by one systemd timer. 2) use "who" to check if there is logged-in tty, then you can skip autologin.

Comment: I did not get your first point. By service, you mean getty?

Comment: You can either modify the getty service, or write a new one by yourself to fit your requirement.(of coz, you might need to mask/disable original one). But I don't have a good knowledge of how tty is being handled by systemd, I might give stupid advises.